# ConstraintLayout in Android studio - How to set aspect ratio constraint similar to Xcode interface builder constraints

Tags: android, android-studio, android-constraintlayout

I'm an iOS developer who has an Android Studio question. In interface builder in Xcode, there is an aspect ratio constraint that can be set to your view to make to view scale according to its set aspect ratio:

[image]

Through searching, I have been unable to find a similar ability in Android Studio. I want to build a 2x6 grid view that scales to all screen sizes similar to this layout:

[image]

In Xcode, I accomplished this by setting the leading, trailing, top and bottom space constraints based on square location in the grid, and then set the aspect ratio to self and self to the aspect ratio of the view containing the subview. How would I best accomplish this in Android Studio using constraint layout?

To further clarify, here is how I want the grid to look at all screen sizes:

[image]

But when I enlarge the container text view holding these buttons, they don't scale to meet the size of their container:

[image]

Update:

I tried the answer provided by @Psest328 and this works scaling the individual grid items, but now I want to maintain the aspect ratio of the grid in both orientation views. Here it is in portrait and in landscape:

[image]
[image]

As you can see the landscape orientation has caused the container view to "skew" to fit the view size. I want it to maintain its shape and aspect ratio.

Comment: please see my edited answer

Comment: I edited to question.

Comment: Hmm... Constraint layout is supposed to preserve aspect across orientation change. Give me a few to look into this

Comment: take a look at this and see if it fixes your issue: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintSet.html

Comment: See my updated answer :)

Comment: You're very welcome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was all done in the graphical interface in AS...

What I did here was lay out 6 buttons.  1 at each corner and 1 on each side in the middle.

1. Select the top 2, right-clicked, and chose "expand horizontally"
2. Select the middle 2, right-clicked, and chose "expand horizontally"
3. Select the bottom 2, right-clicked, and chose "expand horizontally"
4. Select the entire left column (3 buttons), right-clicked and
   selected "expand vertically"
5. Select the entire right column (3 buttons), right-clicked and
   selected "expand vertically"
6. Click the light bulb (infer constraints)

Here's the result:

[image]

**EDIT:**

Per your update, I copied the layout to res/layout-land and repositioned the buttons the way I wanted and did the same steps from before (expand horizontally, then vertically, then infer constraints).

The editor smartly picks the correct layout file when clicking orientation change:
[image]